# Active Directory domain controller fails to load DNS zones on startup

Tags: windows, active-directory, internal-dns

I have a Windows 2019 Standard server that is the sole DC on a small network. Regularly users can't access the networked accounting software on the server. When I try to access the DNS admin on the server, Error logs show DNS event ID 4000.

This procedure corrects the problem:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/dns-zones-do-not-load-event-4000-4007 :

```
net stop kdc
netdom resetpwd /server:mydc.example.local /userd:EXAMPLE\domain_admin /passwordd:*
net start kdc
```

Although I can correct the problem, I don't know why it is happening. This has happened 4 times in 10 days. I have not been able to identify an event on the server that could cause this. What can cause this problem? Where should I be looking for clues?